# AuthorID not being passed to redirect string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box that I need to pass the `authorid` into a hidden field that matches the selected author. 
 I then need to pass that `authorID` to the response.redirect url so the detailed authors page opens with that author's biography information when the button is clicked.
 Below is my code but it does not work.
 How can I get my button to work so the correct authorid is passed everytime the author's name is selected?

```
ImageButton btnFindAuthors = sender as ImageButton;
HiddenField myhiddenfield = btnFindAuthors.NamingContainer.FindControl("hiddenID") as HiddenField;
int myID = Convert.ToInt32(myhiddenfield.Value);
Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Authors_Detail.aspx?id=" + myhiddenfield));
```

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAuthors" Text='<%# Bind("AuthorName") %>' />
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnFindAuthors"  OnClick="btnFindAuthors"/>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="fndAuthors" runat="server" 
             DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" 
             ServicePath="~/WebServices/AuthorsWebService.asmx" 
             ServiceMethod="AutoComplete"
             TargetControlID="txtAuthors" MinimumPrefixLength="3" />             
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("AuthorID") %>' />
```

Author Id:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlAuthors" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Libros %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Libros.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Authors 
                   WHERE AuthorName LIKE ('%' + @Authorname + '%') 
                   ORDER BY AuthorName" 
        <selectParameters> 
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtAuthors" Name="authorname" /> 
        </selectParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: how do you set the value of the hidden field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I stripped out unnecessary things, always keep things simple before adding more features.

Use a code behind aspx page

**Mark Up**

```
<div id="awindow" >
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="mainContent">
    <div style="width: 100%; float: left">    
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFindAuthor" AutoPostBack="true"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnFindAuthor" runat="server" Text="btnFindAuthor" 
            onclick="btnFindAuthor_Click" />        
    </div>            
        <asp:GridView ID="gvAuthors" runat="server">
         <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="AuthorID" 
                            DataNavigateUrlFormatString='~/AuthorsMain/Authors_Detail.aspx?id={0}'
                            DataTextField="AuthorName" 
                            HeaderText="Author Name" />
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindAuthorGrid();
    }

    protected void btnFindAuthor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        BindAuthorGrid();
    }

    private void BindAuthorGrid()
    {
        //Bind search results to AuthorGridView control
        gvAuthors.DataSource = SearchAuthor(txtFindAuthor.Text);
        gvAuthors.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable SearchAuthor(string authorName)
    {

        var searchResultsTable = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Libros"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {   
                var cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                if (authorName != string.Empty)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Authors WHERE AuthorName = @authorName ORDER BY AuthorName ASC";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("authorName", authorName);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Authors", conn);
                }

                //create sql adapter by passing command object
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //fill the search results table
                adapter.Fill(searchResultsTable);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        return searchResultsTable;
    }
```

Comment: Meda, Thank you so much for the above code. I have updated my code with the above logic. Everything looks good except I now have two issues before I can run the code. The error is "Type or namespace 'SQLCommand' could not be found. Are you missing a user directive or an assembly reference?" The same message is also displaying for the SQLAdaptor line.  Including this namespace at the top of the page resolved this error for the SQLConnection: <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>  How do I resolve these other two errors?  This did not happen yesterday.

Comment: I resolved the assembly references but get this error when the page tries to load:  Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'gvAuthors'.  Remove one definition."  I double-checked and everything on my page is the same as the code you provided.  What is the best way to resolve this error?

Comment: the code behind and markup are on the same page.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I added the code behind at the top of the markup page.  The markup language is in the body of the page.  Both are on the same .aspx page.

Comment: @user2821300 is this your first .Net project, can you go to the C# chat ?

Comment: Ok-I'm supposed to be able to create a code behind page via VS but didn't see the + beside my Author_default.aspx page. So, I went to the File -->New option to create a new ascx.cs page.   I could only create an .ascx page.  Something still isn't right though because when I put all of the code behind logic in the .ascx.cs page, most of it shows errors. It looks like something is wrong with my path perhaps?

Comment: -I went to the chat but can not make any comments.  Yes, this is my first big .net project.  I am a VB programmer so this methodology is new to me.

Comment: Strange I upvoted your question so you get enough reputation, but I sent you a gmail chat invitation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39850/discussion-between-meda-and-user2821300)

Comment: I will click the link again.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a long discussion based on the answer from @meda, I now clearly see the source of your problem.

You are facing all these errors and problems because of the architecture and lifecycle of ASP pages. That's really a pain in the neck most of the times. Even when using AJAX, either built-in update panel or extensions.

Based on your code and discussions, I know that you are using the built-in data binding controls to retrieve the data, and mark up the results. 
The first code block must be written inside your ImageButton's click event. Right?

Just set the ImageButton property `PostBackUrl` like this...

`PostBackUrl='~/Authors_Detail.aspx?id=<%# Eval("AuthorId") %>'`

One thing is, there's a slight chance that it might not work. Because you won't have the `AuthorID` value during the first time the page loaded up. Since your text box and image buttons resides in the same binding scope, you might need to manually re-render the whole image button again, to update the property.

I want to give you a good advice. The actual optimal approach in this case is to show the result, author name or image, in a separate data binding panel. Such as a repeater, form view or details view. 
 
Frankly, you won't even need the binding panel for the text box. You are already getting the results with ajax. If you are sure that your result comes out only one record, you can use the form view. Or, use repeater or list view if the result is multiple.

Inside the view where you will show your result, you can render the propery of the control you are gonna use with the code I've shown above. You can use anything, hyperlink, linkbutton, imagebutton, etc. 
 
Since the results for the views are processed server-side, you can ensure that your desired param value is attached to the link in this way.

I know my explanation is a little messy. Please comment out if you can't understand.

Comment: The main problem is, with every ajax request, the entire asp page is reloaded and re-render in the background. Every piece of content is re-rendered. Every data binding control is re-binded. Even if we won't be seeing in the browser that the page is reloading. ASP ajax functionalities works the same way. If you want real dynamic and async call to server, you better use JavaScript ajax, or real ajax frameworks like jQuery. It would be much easier for you. I swear!

Comment: If you are calling to the web service methods, it's worse. ASP ajax doesn't talk to the server in the back and manipulate the DOM in the front. It talks to the server in the back and reload the page silently in the front. So, even you can get the result from the database with ajax call, it would be difficult for it render within the page. I'm not saying it's impossible, but it's a difficult and frustrating work.

Comment: Gurdien, Thank you so much for reviewing my code and for your comments. I am implementing and testing your suggestions. I no longer bind the panel for the textbox and do still get autocomplete results. I am able to follow your explanation and am working on updating the imagebutton tag. I keep getting "tag not properly formed messages". If I am posting the url back to the page, do I even need the additional call to the redirect script?

Comment: I have resolved the issue with the tag not being properly formed. Now I get this error: Error converting data type nvarchar to int. The variable is being passed in the url is the text <%#Eval("AuthorID")%> - not the actual value

Comment: Gurdien,  I am calling a webservice method.  I am adding this feature to some code another group of developers wrote. My personal preference was to use JQuery. You are correct - this is very frustrating.  I am used to just calling a JS event and pass my value through the JS call.

Comment: @user2821300, sorry. It was a little bit of syntax typo. Try like this `PostBackUrl="~/Author_Detail.aspx?id=" + <%# Eval("AuthorID") %>`. But I'm sure it must be some way around.

Comment: @user2821300, I just want to say however you write the code to solve this problem, the optimum approach is **not** to generate the imagebutton, or the link to your author detail page before the user can actually enter the search criteria into your text box. So that when he or she hit Search or enter, the search criteria will be posted back, either by normally or ajax call, to the server. In this way, you can make sure the required values are binded properly to the controls by the server.